# Bit swapping within a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

I am trying to write a program that reads in a text file and then decrypts it following these qualifications:

1. For every 4 bytes `<c0,c1,c2,c3>` swap bytes c2 and c3
2. For every byte `<b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0>` swap bits b3 and b1, and
   swap bits b2 and b0
3. For every 4 bytes `<c0,c1,c2,c3>` XOR bytes c2 and c3 with the
   character 'R'

My program reads in the text file into a dynamic array called 'message'.  Below is the code I implemented for the byte/bit swapping:

```
//Because chars are 1 byte long, just switch elements of the message array  
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < length; i = i+4)
{
    char temp;
    temp = message[i+3];
    message[i+3] = message[i+2];
    message[i+2] = temp;
}

//Second letter of key is 'Y'.  Swap bits b3 and b1, swap bits b2 and b0 in every byte of <b7,b6,b5,b4,b3,b2,b1,b0>
//use bit shifting and bit masks
char mask1 = 0x08; //mask of 00001000 for bit b3
char mask2 = 0x02; //mask of 00000010 for bit b1
char mask3 = 0x04; //mask of 00000100 for bit b2
char mask4 = 0x01; //mask of 00000001 for bit b0

char mask5 = 0xF0; //mask of 11110000 to preserve shifted bits but allow first four through

//and bits together and shift for every byte of message
int s = 0;
for (s = 0; s < length; s = s+1)
{
    char result = ((message[s] & mask1) >> 2 | (message[s] & mask2) << 2);
    char second = ((message[s] & mask3) >> 2 | (message[s] & mask4) << 2);
    message[s] = ((result | second) & mask5);
}

//Third letter of the key is 'R'.  XOR bytes c1 and c0 with k3 of bytes <c0,c1,c2,c3>
int j = 0;
for (j = 0; j < length; j = j+4)
{
    message[j] = message[j] ^ 'R';
    message[j+1] = message[j+1] ^ 'R';
}

//display message
printf("The message is: ");
for (i = 0; i < length; i = i+1)
{
    printf("%c", message[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

The final output of the program turns all of the characters of the message to 'R'.  So if the message was 5 characters in length, the output would be "RRRRR".

I don't understand why these swaps aren't working!  Any tips or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Your comments don't match the code all that well... For example, you appear to be XORing R into bytes 0, 1, not 2, 3 as you claim.

Comment: The code to swap bits ends up setting `message[s]` to zero. You should use a debugger on that code, or use `printf` to print out `result`, `second` and `message[s]` at the end of the loop.

Comment: message[s] = (message[s] & mask5) | (result | second)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting all Rs is here...

```
for (s = 0; s < length; s = s+1)
{
    char result = ((message[s] & mask1) >> 2 | (message[s] & mask2) << 2);
    char second = ((message[s] & mask3) >> 2 | (message[s] & mask4) << 2);
    message[s] = ((result | second) & mask5);
}
```

`mask5` clears the bottom four bits.

I think what you meant was...

```
for (s = 0; s < length; s = s+1)
{
    char b3 = message[s] & mask1;
    char b2 = message[s] & mask2;
    char b1 = message[s] & mask3;
    char b0 = message[s] & mask4;

    message[s] &= ~(mask1 | mask2 | mask3 | mask4);
    message[s] |= (b3 >> 2 | b1 << 2 | b2 >> 2 | b0 << 2);
}
```